# Resize UICollectionViewCell

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ios10

In my app I have UICollectionView with FlowLayout (vertical). and in collection cell I have label for header and textView for content. Content length may be vary, short or long. I need to implement cell's autoresizing. in my CustomCell class I overrided this method:

```
override func preferredLayoutAttributesFitting(_ layoutAttributes: UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes) -> UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes {

    let attributes = layoutAttributes.copy() as! UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes
    let desiredHeight = systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height
    attributes.frame.size.height = desiredHeight

    return attributes
}
```

in ViewController class in viewDidLoad() I wrote this:

```
if let layout = collectionView.collectionViewLayout as? UICollectionViewFlowLayout {
    layout.estimatedItemSize = CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 120)
}
```

app runs w/o any errors, but cell resizing only after scrolling, not when view appears on screen. is there any issue to fix that?

before scrolling

[image]

after scrolling

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you have an update constraint issue, this is why when you scroll the content, you have the constraints already updated and get the right height. Before calling systemLayoutSizeFitting(UILayoutFittingCompressedSize).height you should call layoutIfNeeded()